# How to update a react redux state with object spread properly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, ecmascript-next

I have a user state saved in localStorage that looks like this after authentication:

```
  "user" : {
  "first_name":"test19", 
  "last_name":"test19",
  "email":"test19@testmail.com",
  "token" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjcyMCwia"
   ...
```

Now I also have a form that triggers an action to update the user's state once the server returned the updated info and my reducer looks like this:

```
case userConstants.UPDATE_USER:
      return {
        loggedIn: true,
        ...state,
        user: action.user
      };
```

So far so good except that the returned object from the server doesn't include a token, and the result of the reducer above is a new state without the token which I need.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to avoid losing the token after an update. Update your reducer like this.

```
case userConstants.UPDATE_USER:
    return {
        loggedIn: true,
        ...state,
        user: {
            ...action.user,
            token: state.user.token
        }
    };
```

The idea here is that, you will override the token attribute of the action.user with the one in the state(without mutating), before returning the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Adding state first, it will contain an old version of the user, overwriting user after the destruction of the main state:

```
case userConstants.UPDATE_USER:
      return {
        loggedIn: true,
        ...state,
        user:{
           ...action.user,
           ...state.user,
        },
      };
```

Comment: sorry dude your solution is not updating the state at all, is it because the ...state.user overrides the ...action.user?